# rewrite the whole URL in a local network webpage on easyphp

Tags: web, lan, easyphp

I have an easyphp web server hosting a sample website. The website is accessible via the following URL:

192.888.888.2/website

What are the possible ways to make it look like

www.fakeurl.com?

The network is not connected to internet as is for the purpose that people can access to the website via their smartphones when connecting to my network.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your IP address with a DNS service. There are some free services available such as dynamicdns or zoneedit. This is the only way you can resolve the IP to the domain name. If the users are on your network, you can force the DNS translation using the hosts file on each computer.

Comment: The network is not connected to internet. It is only bunch of devices connected to each other. These services seem to work only online, no?